# Diffrence between JRockit in BEA Weblogic and Sun Java Implementation

Tags: java, sun, jrockit, bea

We have different JRE implementation from 2 vendors one is Jrockit from BEA and other is from Sun.
In my project the document clearly states to use the Jrockit implementation from BEA. So i want to know the differences and upperhand of Jrockit over the standard sun JVM.

thanks
Punith

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Firstly, BEA and Sun were both taken over by Oracle.  So JRockit and HotSpot are now both Oracle products.

JRockit started out as a faster JVM than Hotspot for server-side code, but a lot of work has been done since then to make Hotspot faster, so it is not clear if that still applies.  The other thing that I recall is that JRockit has (had) a different heap sizing strategy.  In particular, you didn't need to provide a fixed upper bound for the heap.  This could be a good thing or a bad thing, depending on your perspective.

From a purely functional stand-point, JRockit and HotSpot implementations of the same Java baseline *should* be virtually identical.

Here are some other resources (from a Google search):

- ["Comparison Between Sun JDK And Oracle JRockit"](http://weblogic-wonders.com/weblogic/2010/12/06/comparison-between-sun-jdk-and-oracle-jrockit/)
- [JRockit JVM versus HotSpot JVM](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8068717/jrockit-jvm-versus-hotspot-jvm)
- [Wikipedia's JRockit page](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JRockit).

Comment: Not sure about this answer, but Jrockit was used for the server side large applications. As u mentioned may be bcoz of the heap size strategy, And as both are in hands of oracle now need to watch as how they will trade with 2 some how similar products.

Comment: For instance, [Java 7 Update 4 Release Notes](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/7u4-relnotes-1575007.html) gives some example of functionality reimplemented from JRockit. Seems that they will eventually merge them? Who knows...

Answer (score 1):

Technically they are both from Oracle now. ;)

Given most of the developers for the former Sun JVM are from the JRockit team, I suspect the difference will become smaller over time (i.e. there is only one development team for both products)