# Differences between JVMs in different JRE's

Tags: jvm, java

There are a number of JRE's(Suns, Oracles, ) with different JVMs (hotspot, IcedTea).

So are there any major differences between them all? Are they similar in that to linux distros where one will focus on security, another on usability?

Is there much difference in terms of speed between them all or are they more influenced by hardware?

I've tried to get some nice explanations or even examples of different JVM's but haven't managed to find much information. Any help appreciated.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Differences between JVM implementations](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/747360/differences-between-jvm-implementations)

Comment: You might want to check out this question:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/747360/differences-between-jvm-implementations And this one http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8068717/jrockit-jvm-versus-hotspot-jvm

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may find the blog post [Understanding the various JDKs](http://openj.dk/2011/05/19/understanding-the-various-jdks/) useful.

> IcedTea provides webstart, plugin implementations, a build harness
>   (and more) for OpenJDK to help the various Linux ditros do their own
>   JDK builds.  A typical Java Application Developer probably isn’t going
>   to use IcedTea, instead, they’d consume the JDK provided by their
>   Linux distro provider.

Comment: Thats excellent. One last thing if you don't mind. Is it the general consensus that Suns JVM was/is the fastest available to date?

Comment: Obviously, Hotspot VM is an ergonomic and optimized JVM. http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/tech/index-jsp-136373.html

Answer (score 1):

IMHO, There is not much difference between them as they are all based on OpenJDK to some degree or another.

The most significant difference is that JVMs are only available on specific OSes. e.g. On IBM AIX, you won't get the Oracle/Sun JRE.